# SQL Select top 100 columns be specific column names or indices

Tags: sql

This works to select top 100 columns, but it gives me all of the columns

`select top 100 * from dw.test`

This works, but it gives me endless rows,

`select Slot, ID from dw.test`

I need to select top 100 rows that only show these two columns `Slot, ID`

I cannot get it to work no matter how I try to combine them,
Please help create this query. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `select TOP 100 Slot, ID from dw.test`?

Comment: Also, why are you not using an `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select TOP(100) Slot, ID from dw.test ORDER BY Slot, ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me which RDBMS is being used, but one of the following should work:

```sql
SELECT TOP(100) Slot, ID FROM dw.test;
```

`Limit` instead?

```sql
SELECT Slot, ID FROM dw.test LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: I get a new error, Ambiguous column name "ID". Looking at it, there are two column names with the same name. Is there any way to specify columns by number and not name? Or is there a better way to resolve it

Comment: This is another question, @Mich. Did my answer solved the (initial) issue?